# How to provide a Redux POST Action

Tags: javascript, redux

Is the code below the right approach to provide POST requests in the redux application design?

The code woks fine but I'm not sure if it is again the architecture for any reason.

```
export const SITES_RECEIVED = 'SITES_RECEIVED';

//@private
function sitesReceived(sites) {
  return {
    type: SITES_RECEIVED,
    sites: sites
  };
}

//@public
export const sitesFetch = () => {
  return dispatch => {

    fetch('http://localhost:3000/')
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.text();
      }).then(function(body) {
        return JSON.parse(body);
      }).then(function(json) {
        dispatch(sitesReceived(json));
      })
  };
}
```

*Requirements: redux, redux-thunk*

Comment: This is a possible way to do it. Your approach is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right. No problem.
This approach is listed in official Redux documentation.
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html#async-action-creators

Comment: Yes, I have tried to reduce the official documentation to the absolute minimal code.

I'm surprised that the AJAX call as the most common issue have so few examples online.

Comment: Uh, Redux is not a typical full-stack framework and focuses on the state management, it's not a major concern for the framework. If you need an architecture to build an application contains more complexed AJAX requests, please consider using [Middleware](http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/Middleware.html) or [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga).